# Charachter to integer conversion in R without loosing precision

Tags: integer

I want to convert the below charachter (idmov) to integer. How can I do that using R programming/Revolution R?

idmov <- '9208205928594750000,00'

> str(idmov)
>    chr "9208205928594750000,00"

I tried

> idmov2 <- as.integer(idmov)
>   Warning message:
>   NAs introduced by coercion

(did not work)

> idmove2 <- strtoi(idmov, base = 16L)
>   idmove2
>   [1] NA

Any suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: That number is too big to store in a 4 byte integer. `.Machine$integer.max==2147483647`.

Comment: And the other problem is the comma separator; R requires a decimal separator. You can use `as.double(gsub(',','.',idmov))` to coerce to double, although you'll lose a little precision.

Comment: Another approach is the [`gmp`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html) package, which provides multiple-precision arithmetic. `library('gmp'); as.bigz(gsub(',.*','',idmov));`.